# C++ ostream overload of typedef array pointer parameter

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, typedef, function-parameter, extraction-operator

How can I avoid creating "typedef Point* pPoint;" for the 2nd parameter in the "<<"-overloading function?

What would be the right way to do that? Where can I read more about it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef float Point[3];
typedef Point* pPoint;


ostream & operator << (std::ostream &os, const pPoint & p )
    {
        int size = sizeof(p);
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            os << "[" << p[i][0] << "," << p[i][2] << "," << p[i][2] << "]" << endl;
        }

        return os;
    }

int main() {

    Point corners[8] = {
    { 1, -1, -5},
    { 1, -1, -3},
    { 1, 1, -5},
    { 1, 1, -3},
    {-1, -1, -5},
    {-1, -1, -3},
    {-1, 1, -5},
    {-1, 1, -3}
    };

    cout << "Point:" << corners<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code might work if you are compiling in 64 bit system, but it is merely a coincidence. `sizeof(p)` is size of a pointer, not the array it points to.

You might want to replace the array of Point with an STL container or make your operator templated by array size and pass reference to array.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for:

```
template<size_t N>
ostream & operator<< (std::ostream &os, Point const (&p)[N])
```

where you use `N` as the count in the loop condition.

This passes the whole array by reference, and so `N` is available for use in the function.

Your existing code passes a pointer to the first row instead, so you have no way of retrieving the size `8` . Instead you use the garbage value `sizeof(p)` which is the number of bytes required to store a pointer, nothing to do with your array dimension.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the explanation. correcting the above code.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 typedef float Point[3];

template<size_t N>
ostream & operator<< (std::ostream &os, Point const (&p)[N])
{
    int size = sizeof(p)/sizeof(*p);

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        os << "[" << p[i][0] << "," << p[i][2] << "," << p[i][2] << "]" << endl;
    }

    return os;
}

int main() {

Point corners[4] = {
            { 1, -1, -5},
            { 1, -1, -3},
            { 1, 1, -5},
            { 1, 1, -3},
            };

cout << "Point:" << corners<< endl;

return 0;
}
```